# Why I am getting this ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/assets/application.js")

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets, precompile

application.js not serving on production heroku
I spent days trying to solve this issue everything works fine locally but in heroku few things are not working at all. such as link_to method::delete

my heroku logs -t

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.712886+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.712886+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.712887+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.712887+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.712888+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/server.rb:307:in `block in start_thread'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.712888+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-30T01:07:53.712888+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-30T01:07:53.717837+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/assets/application.js" host=mobile-implant-lab.herokuapp.com request_id=882701e3-4706-4089-9a58-9bf704908181 fwd="24.85.18.207" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=1829 protocol=https
2020-12-30T01:07:53.734605+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-c89e6fc7884f4c92e785833fd1c46c15f42f2c4a7845dd393b2f85c861554cdb.css" host=mobile-implant-lab.herokuapp.com request_id=b0740ac3-4a32-4d88-9afc-703ea284de67 fwd="24.85.18.207" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=133 protocol=https
2020-12-30T01:07:53.746883+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-d360a99b8e1c4dc7c4dc2ed720b8c39d1234a60be3591c0d8c5dfee211e6d3ba.js" host=mobile-implant-lab.herokuapp.com request_id=1bfb3239-625a-4c36-8294-6b97685166db fwd="24.85.18.207" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=133 protocol=https
2020-12-30T01:07:53.864359+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" for 24.85.18.207 at 2020-12-30 01:07:53 +0000
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874958+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874962+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"):
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874963+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874963+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874964+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874964+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874965+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874965+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874966+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874966+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874967+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874967+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874968+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874968+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874969+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874969+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874970+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874970+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874971+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874971+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874971+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874972+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874972+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874972+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/server.rb:307:in `block in start_thread'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874973+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-30T01:07:53.874973+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-30T01:07:53.880600+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" host=mobile-implant-lab.herokuapp.com request_id=b2f38529-db44-40ee-bd29-bcdfccb58b28 fwd="24.85.18.207" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=404 bytes=1829 protocol=https
2020-12-30T01:07:53.881860+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/lubnasammanlogo-904d60f516b56d59a26594d28731f7538705be42c40533b6ac9a644b77bf66d6.png" host=mobile-implant-lab.herokuapp.com request_id=ef67c6e1-f686-4d74-b5ad-8fda93025820 fwd="24.85.18.207" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=304 bytes=133 protocol=https
2020-12-30T01:07:53.903836+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/assets/application.js" for 24.85.18.207 at 2020-12-30 01:07:53 +0000
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906478+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906480+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/assets/application.js"):
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906505+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906506+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906506+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906507+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906507+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906508+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906508+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906509+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906509+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906510+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906511+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906511+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906521+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.11.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906522+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906522+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906522+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906523+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906523+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906524+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906524+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906525+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
2020-12-30T01:07:53.906525+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/server.rb:307:in `block in start_thread'
Here my production.rb

Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.serve_static_files = true
  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true
 

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
    config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true


end
```

my application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require sweetalert2
//= require sweet-alert2-rails
//= require cocoon 
//= require sweet-alert-confirm
```

my application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MobileImplantLab</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', "data-turbolinks-track" => true%>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```rb
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    
    
    # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
    gem 'rails', '4.2.11.1'
    # Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
    gem 'pg', '~> 0.20.0'
    # Use SCSS for stylesheets
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
    # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
    # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
    # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
    
    # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
    gem 'turbolinks'
    # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
    # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
    
    # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
    # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
    
    # Use Unicorn as the app server
    # gem 'unicorn'
    
    # Use Capistrano for deployment
    # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
    
    group :development, :test do
      # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
      gem 'byebug'
    end
    
    group :development do
      # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
      gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
    
      # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
      gem 'spring'
    end
    
    gem 'devise'
    group :development, :test do
      gem "interactive_editor"
      gem "hirb"
      gem "awesome_print"
      gem 'byebug'
    end
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'mail_form'
    gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.12.0'
    
    gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~>3.2.0'
    
    gem "paperclip"
    
    gem 'aws-sdk-s3'
    gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
    
    gem 'thor', '0.19.1'
    gem 'google-api-client', require: 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
    gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
    gem "recaptcha", require: "recaptcha/rails"
    gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.4.0'
    
    gem 'activeadmin'
    gem 'rails-assets-sweetalert2', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
    gem 'sweet-alert2-rails'
    gem 'sweet-alert-confirm'
    gem "cocoon"
    gem 'bigdecimal', '1.3.5'
    gem 'bundler', '1.17.3'
```

in application.rb

```rb
    require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
    require "rails"
    # Pick the frameworks you want:
    require "active_model/railtie"
    require "active_job/railtie"
    require "active_record/railtie"
    require "action_controller/railtie"
    require "action_mailer/railtie"
    require "action_view/railtie"
    require "sprockets/railtie"
    # require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
    
    # Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
    # you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
    Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
    
    module MobileImplantLab
      class Application < Rails::Application
        config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
        config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos"
        # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
        # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
        # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    
        # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
        # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
        # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
    
        # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
        # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
        # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
    
        # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
        config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
      end
    end
```

I tried to run this command

```
$ heroku run rake assets:precompile
Running rake assets:precompile on ⬢ mobile-implant-lab... up, run.8931 (Standard-1X)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:111: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use BigDecimal() method instead.
I, [2020-12-28T19:46:55.818346 #4]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-e57be3269d79ff2275ae1cbfec657d777c6e4dc7d27f3ba5feaeebfdee1ba0c4.js
I, [2020-12-28T19:46:55.818855 #4]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-e57be3269d79ff2275ae1cbfec657d777c6e4dc7d27f3ba5feaeebfdee1ba0c4.js.gz
```

Any help will be appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Heruku runs app inside a container, this differs from running locally or on a bare metal server. For example - any files that your app writes to "disk" alongside it's source will be lost at some point in time, and also these are not visible between container instances. So running remote precompilation via `heroku run` will not have any effect.

Make sure that nothing from `public/assets` gets committed (or was committed) to the repository, so heroku will try running precompilation during slug build phase.
Other option is the opposite - if your assets change rarely and are small - you can commit entire `public/assets` after local compilation. See [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#the-rails-3-asset-pipeline)

Comment: How to Make sure that nothing from public/assets gets committed (or was committed) to the repository?

Comment: @nourza check your repo contents for that, for example - `git ls-files public/assets`